# UILabel text in table view cell disappearing on scroll even when set in didSet block

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My problem: the text on some of my UILabels (the answers for the questions) in a particular cell are blank when I scroll down (only the 3rd through 7th labels, as you'll see in my code the first and second are always set and seem to magically work no matter what).  It only happens for some cells, for most cells when they render the first time it's correct (not always, though).

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now and can't seem to fix it.  I'm pretty sure it has to do with table cell reuse, but I set the data in a `didSet` block in my custom table cell and even tried the `prepareForReuse()` override as suggested here: [Stop the reuse of custom cells Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309405/stop-the-reuse-of-custom-cells-swift).  Nothing seems to work, I still have some cells (only some, not all!) that lose some of their text when I scroll through my tableView.  What am I missing?

Here is the `didSet` block for my custom cell class `QuestionCustomCell` (and if it helps, the `NSLog` printout does show the correct text that should be in the cell when I scroll down, but it doesn't render):

```
var cellQuestion: Question! {
    didSet {
        questionLabel.text = cellQuestion.topQuestion
        questionLabel.sizeToFit()
        //definitely at least 2 answers
        switchLabel1.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[0]
        switchLabel2.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[1]
        if(cellQuestion.theResponses[2] == nil) {
            switch3.isHidden = true
            switchLabel3.isHidden = true
        } else {
            switch3.isHidden = false
            switchLabel3.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[2]
            let questionName : String = cellQuestion.topQuestion
            NSLog("question: "+questionName+" response: "+cellQuestion.theResponses[2]!)
        }
        if(cellQuestion.theResponses[3] == nil) {
            switch4.isHidden = true
            switchLabel4.isHidden = true
        } else {
            switch4.isHidden = false
            switchLabel4.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[3]
            let questionName : String = cellQuestion.topQuestion
            NSLog("question: "+questionName+" response: "+cellQuestion.theResponses[3]!)
        }
        if(cellQuestion.theResponses[4] == nil) {
            switch5.isHidden = true
            switchLabel5.isHidden = true
        } else {
            switch5.isHidden = false
            switchLabel5.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[4]
            let questionName : String = cellQuestion.topQuestion
            NSLog("question: "+questionName+" response: "+cellQuestion.theResponses[4]!)
        }
        if(cellQuestion.theResponses[5] == nil) {
            switch6.isHidden = true
            switchLabel6.isHidden = true
        } else {
            switch6.isHidden = false
            switchLabel6.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[5]
            let questionName : String = cellQuestion.topQuestion
            NSLog("question: "+questionName+" response: "+cellQuestion.theResponses[5]!)
        }
        if(cellQuestion.theResponses[6] == nil) {
            switch7.isHidden = true
            switchLabel7.isHidden = true
        } else {
            switch7.isHidden = false
            switchLabel7.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[6]
            let questionName : String = cellQuestion.topQuestion
            NSLog("question: "+questionName+" response: "+cellQuestion.theResponses[6]!)
        }

        restorePriorAnswer()
    }
}
```

And here is `restorePriorAnswer()` (I use it so the cells remember whether the switch was off or on when reused - that does work):

```
func restorePriorAnswer ( )
{
    if(cellQuestion.theAnswer != nil)
    {
        self.cellDelegate.restorePrior(forCell: self, forShortName: cellQuestion.shortName, subAction: "\(cellQuestion.theAnswer!.answerSelect)")
        print("Prior answer was \(cellQuestion.theAnswer!.answerSelect)")


        switch(cellQuestion.theAnswer!.answerSelect)
        {
        case 0:
            switch1.isOn = true
            break
        case 1:
            switch2.isOn = true
            break
        case 2:
            switch3.isOn = true
            break
        case 3:
            switch4.isOn = true
            break
        case 4:
            switch5.isOn = true
            break
        case 5:
            switch6.isOn = true
            break
        case 6:
            switch7.isOn = true
            break
        default:
            self.cellDelegate.restorePrior(forCell: self, forShortName: "Control", subAction: "restorePriorAnswer (Bad Select Value)")
            break
        }
    }
    else
    {
        switch1.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch2.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch3.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch4.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch5.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch6.setOn(false, animated: false)
        switch7.setOn(false, animated: false)
    }

}
```

And here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:QuestionCustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuse, for: indexPath) as! QuestionCustomCell
    if((currentQuestion?.canSubsume())!) {
        if((currentQuestion?.shouldDoSubsume())!) {
            //since this apparently refreshes random rows, we need to hard-code which row goes where
            if(indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.cellQuestion = currentQuestion
            } else { 
                let rowQuestion: Question = (currentQuestion?.getSubsumeList().getQuestion(shortID: currSubsumeArray![indexPath.row - 1]))!
                cell.cellQuestion = rowQuestion
            }
        } else {
            //there should only be one cell at this point - the first one
            cell.cellQuestion = currentQuestion
            //print out the first question, just to make sure...
            let logStringOne : String = "the current question: " + (currentQuestion?.topQuestion)!
            NSLog(logStringOne)
            let logString : String = "the first subsumed question: " + (currentQuestion?.subsumeList!.firstQuestion)!
            NSLog(logString)
        }
    } else {
        cell.cellQuestion = currentQuestion
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.cellDelegate = self
    return cell
}
```

Please let me know if I'm missing any code you think is helpful to solve the problem.  Everything else works besides the labels - the switches remember if they were on or off when scrolling back and forth, the appropriate switches are hidden if their appropriate slot in the answers array is nil, and all other text is as it should be - except some of the labels for the answers, which is the problem.  As I mentioned, I tried the `prepareForReuse()` method but it didn't do anything, so I took it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I apologize, it was staring me in the face for several hours and I didn't realize it.  In the `didSet` block I had hidden the labels if they weren't supposed to be used, like this:

```
if(cellQuestion.theResponses[2] == nil) {
    switch3.isHidden = true
    switchLabel3.isHidden = true
} else {
    switch3.isHidden = false
    switchLabel3.text = cellQuestion.theResponses[2]
}
```

but in the `else` block, I didn't unhide them...when a cell was loaded fresh and not reused, it had no issue because the label had never been hidden previously.  But in a reused cell, it was, and so the label didn't exist for those cells that were reused.

So, each of these `if/else` blocks should have a `switchLabelx.isHidden = false`in them, with x being the appropriate number.  Not that I wish staring at code for hours on anyone, but hopefully someone will find this useful.